# why this msvsmon.exe does not appear error message gives when calling to the web service in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wsdl, visual-studio-debugging

I'm calling to a wsdl web service.this is part of my code

```
public string SendXML(string arguments)
    {
        string output;
        try
        {

            ws_operateService client = new ws_operateService();
            string mm = "MethodName";
            wssigateway_ttInRow[] tt_In = new wssigateway_ttInRow[2];
            tt_In[0] = new wssigateway_ttInRow();
            tt_In[0].ParNam = "MethodName";
            tt_In[0].ParPos = 0;
            tt_In[0].ParVal = "POST";
            tt_In[1] = new wssigateway_ttInRow();
            tt_In[1].ParNam = "XMLDocumentIn";
            tt_In[1].ParPos = 1;
            tt_In[1].ParVal = arguments;
            wssigateway_ttOutRow[] tt_Out = new wssigateway_ttOutRow[3];
            tt_Out[0] = new wssigateway_ttOutRow();
            tt_Out[0].ParNam = "ContentType";
            tt_Out[0].ParPos = 0;
            tt_Out[0].ParVal = "";
            tt_Out[1] = new wssigateway_ttOutRow();
            tt_Out[1].ParNam = "Result";
            tt_Out[1].ParPos = 1;
            tt_Out[1].ParVal = "";
            tt_Out[2] = new wssigateway_ttOutRow();
            tt_Out[2].ParNam = "XMLDocumentOut";
            tt_Out[2].ParPos = 2;
            tt_Out[2].ParVal = "";

            string lout;
            client.SetUrl(Url);
            string result = client.wssigateway("wsinvokeservice", "svcmsgxml.bldximsgin", tt_In, ref tt_Out, out lout);//this line
            output = tt_Out[2].ParVal;
        }
         catch(Exception e) {     
             output = e.Message;
         }
        return output;
    }
```

in the commented line it gives this error message.

[image]

I do not have idea what is going on .I'm new to this field. please help me with this.thank you very much

Comment: Have you ever tried to use `telnet` between your machine and remote machine on specific port?

Comment: no, I never tried and I don't know.why  to connect with remote machine

Comment: Check this link and be sure you done all steps. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: normally do we have to do this to connect with external webservices that has credentials